# Redirect and pass data from controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect from a controller and pass data;

```
 public function fortest(Request $request)
{
     $user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
     if (isset($user))
     {   
        return redirect('/fortest2', ['user'=>$user]);//compact('user'));
        //return $this->fortest2($request);
     }
}
public function fortest2(Request $request)
{
    return $request->name;
}

Route::get('/fortest', 'UserController@fortest');
Route::get('/fortest2/', 'UserController@fortest2');
```

The code works when calling the controller directly from within the controller. The data type has a model. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data in a redirect, you can use the `with()` method.
You have to append it to the redirect like so:

```
redirect('/fortest2')->with('data', 'value');
```

It will be saved in your current session, so it will be only persistent until you refresh the page again. If you want to store it for longer you have to go with a database/textfile etc. You can then check for it using

```
if (session()->has('data')) { // check if it exists
    $value = session('data'); // to retrieve value
}
```

You can also send errors with the redirect (from validation i.e.) using `withErrors()`, sending the current input with it using `withInput()`

---

For what you want to achieve, try using this in your controller. This will just send the users name with the redirect:

```
$user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
redirect('/fortest2')->with('username', $user->name);
```

You can then access is via `session('username')`

Comment: It works. But how do I get data from $value. If I try return $value->name, there is a "trying to get property of a non-object". Is session an array I have to access lie session['id']?

Comment: Session is a helper function. You basically call $_SESSION['data'] if you call session('data'). I dont know if there is a way to get the key, for what do you need to fetch the key?

Comment: I am trying to display the name of the object but I get the above error.

Comment: So if I got you right, you are trying to display the users name? Or 'data' in my example above?

Comment: Yes. If not passing the object, then passing the id so that the other function can retrieve it from the database.

Comment: See the bottom of my answer, i think this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sessions to pass data when using redirect:

```
return redirect('/fortest2')->with('data', 'some data');
```

Then [get data from session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#retrieving-data):

```
$data = session('data');
```

Or you can persist data in DB and then get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
public function fortest(Request $request)
{
  $user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
  if(isset($user))
  {   
    return redirect('/fortest2/$user->name');
  }
}
public function fortest2($name)
{
  return $name;
}
```

Your route

```
Route::get('/fortest', 'UserController@fortest');
Route::get('/fortest2/{$name}', 'UserController@fortest2');
```