# Redirect from controller to named route with data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm gonna try to explain my problem:

- I have a named route called 'form.index' where I show a html form.
- In FormController I retrieve all form data.
- After do some stuff with these data, I want to redirect to another named route 'form.matches' with some items collection.

**URLS**

> form.index   -> websiteexample/form
>
> form.matches -> websiteexample/matches

**FormController**

```
public function match(FormularioRequest $request)
{
    // Some stuffs

    $list = /*Collection*/;

    return redirect()->route('form.matches')->with(compact('list'));
}

public function matches()
{
    // How to retrieve $list var here?
    return view('form.views.matches')->with(compact('list'));
}
```

**The problem:**

When the redirects of match function occurs, I get an error "Undefined variable: list' in matches funcion.

Comment: `public function matches($list)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39916324/10182897 solution already available i think you can check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect and pass data from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916283/redirect-and-pass-data-from-controller)

Comment: @Ashish I already tried that solution, but it did not work for me.

Comment: @Alvaro_SE try using session for it.

Comment: Sorry @Ashish, it works! I was trying to get the variable that was not. I'm stupid, I'm so sorry. All morning lost cause of a name error.

Comment: @Alvaro_SE you can give points to Others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function match(Request $request)
 {
// Operations

$list = //Data Collection;

return redirect()->route('form.matches')->with('list',$list);
}

In view
@if(Session::has('list'))
<div>  
{!!Session::get('list')!!}
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redirect::route() to redirect to a named route and pass an array of parameters as the second argument

```
Redirect::route('route.name',array('param1' => $param1,'param2' => $param2));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: And then how do I get the collection in the matches() function?